# In Java how would I reference a whole object within a its own class?

Tags: java, object

I have this in a class called Pokemon and what I would like to do is reference the current object as a whole and pass it through int .use. (I know that you can reference specific pieces of data based on the object using it so I would assume you could do it for the object as a whole) Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public boolean attack(int m,Pokemon p) {
        boolean hit = true;
        //check what move the use and take away a pp and return it 
        if (m == 1) {
            hit = m1.use(p.getType1(), p.getType2(),**this is where I want to pass the object**);
            if (hit == true) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        } else if (m == 2) {
            hit = m2.use(p.getType1(), p.getType2(),**this is where I want to pass the object**);

            if (hit == true) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        } else if (m == 3) {
            hit = m3.use(p.getType1(), p.getType2(),**this is where I want to pass the object**);

            if (hit == true) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        } else if (m == 4) {
            hit = m4.use(p.getType1(), p.getType2(),**this is where I want to pass the object**);

            if (hit == true) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: see the defination of `public boolean attack(int m,Pokemon p) ` - that is how you pass an entire Object.  But what on earth is `m1` etc? What type of Object is it and how is `use` defined?

Comment: *FYI:* `if (hit == true) { return true; } else { return false; }` should be just `return hit;`. The `if` statement is superfluous.

Comment: If you had an array of `m?` objects all this code could be done in a couple of lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use keyword **`this`** to refer to (the whole of) the current object.

As the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3) says it:

> Keyword `this` denotes a value that is a reference to the object for which the instance method or default method was invoked.